# How to fix FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, parsing, exception, java.util.scanner

I have a text file in the same package as the class I'm accessing it through, so I don't understand why I'm getting this exception. Where did I go wrong here?

```
public static boolean someMethod(){
File f = new File("input.txt");
try{
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
s.useDelimiter(""); //I want to parse by one character at a time
while(s.hasNext()){
...
}
}catch (FileNotFoundException e){
...
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: The file goes at the root directory of the your project, not the same directory of the class.

Comment: Where is this root directory located? Sorry I'm new to this :(

Answer (score 0):

`new File("input.txt")` is relative to your current working dir. If you want to access packaged files, you can use [`getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Comment: meaning it should be in the src folder instead?

Comment: Depends on what you want your code to do. If `input.txt` is part of your project (settings or whatever), then put it in your src (or better, some additional resources folder added to your build path) and load it with `getResourceAsStream("/input.txt")`. If `input.txt` is external data your tool works with, then access it with `new File("/path/to/input.txt")`.